# New pattern question: $2, 7, 26, 101, 400$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Same Mom trying to help daughter here.  Once I know how to explain this pattern, can you tell me what I'd call this area of math so I can go re-teach myself?  I feel like I could have done this in high school, but it's all gone from lack of use...

$2, 7, 26, 101, 400$

I've fooled around with some $a(x) + b(y) =$ differences, but nothing.  Is this really middle school math?   Thank you thank you all!

Comment: You multiply by 4, take away 1. Then multiply by 4, take away 2. Then 4 and 3. Then 4 and 4. Etc. To be honest, mathematicians would react to this as not being math, because the real problem is to guess what was in the mind of the person setting the problem. What is clear is that the skills needed to solve problems like these are mostly to do with being good at arithmetic.

Comment: In what context did this pattern come up?  Without more information, there is absolutely no way of knowing what the pattern describes or what the next term might be.  One *possibility* would be $a_{n+1} = 4a_n - n$ with $a_1 = 2$, but it could just as easily be something else.

Comment: Pattern recognition is a skill, really, rather than an area of math. This is because there is actually no mathematical definition of a "right answer." Mathematicians use this skill, but it is used to build a conjecture about the sequence, not an assertion that you've gotten a right answer. Not sure what I'd call this skill beyond "sequence recognition." Nowadays, too many of us use OEIS for such things. :)

Comment: Fooling around with the series in general is the way to approach these things.

Comment: Now what if the next number is 39?

Comment: Well these assignments always assume the simplest possible pattern rule.

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo I whole-heartedly disagree with this falling under the description of "algebra."  If anything, depending on context, it may be better described as discrete mathematics / recurrence relations.

Comment: @adjan "Simplest possible" is not always obvious, and certainly not well-defined in most cases.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I think your point is well-taken in general, but I can't think of a rule that fits this series that Occam's Razor treats as nicely. ¶ I wouldn't react positively to an answer that merely said, "This could be anything.  These series questions are dumb."  I'd expect an answer along those lines to give a few examples of different rules that matched the given start to the sequence, in order to illustrate that the question is open-ended (which it surely is).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Granted.  But mathematical intuition is not well-defined.  Suppose this is a homework question.  It's not out of the question that one of its aims is to develop that intuition, and to that end, a thoughtful answer (whether it gives David's answer, or some other one) goes some way toward achieving that aim.

Comment: I would initially labeled it as "discrete" math, but after reading the first two words of the title "Same Mom", I changed it to algebra to fit more of a general audience.

Comment: @kf-Sansoo, do not people use Algebra in general, if the field the problem might belong to, is not clear and involves some sort of manipulation of terms? Sadly I don't know better words myself, maybe arithmetic or push-around-some-numbers-mathematics..

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like rather than teaching algebra, etc, they're really testing persistence.  And willingness to sit and try a million different solutions ad naseum.  Ah, well.

Comment: @KTA What got me thinking along those lines was that each number is roughly four times the number before it. That's really obvious if you look at the last two.

Comment: I'd just like to clarify that my comment that "mathematicians would react to this as not being math" was *not* intended as an argument in favour of closing the question. It is clear that the overlap in skills needed to solve this problem and incontrovertibly mathematical ones is very high. Also, since these pattern recognition questions do appear on standardized tests, whatever our frustration with them, in an *institutional* sense, they are math. And frankly, I think the site should be as helpful as possible to people who have encountered problems in the course of their math studies.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}2\times4-1&=7\\
7\times4-2&=26\\
26\times4-3&=101\\
101\times4-4&=400\\
400\times4-5&=1595\\\cdots\end{align}$$

By solving the linear recurrence $a_0=2,a_n=4a_{n-1}-n$,

$$a_n=\frac{14\cdot4^n+3n+4}9.$$

---

The general solution of the homogenous equation is

$$a_n=C4^n.$$

Searching a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation, we try

$$a_n=An+B,$$

which gives

$$An+B=4(A(n-1)+B)-n,\\A=\frac13,B=\frac49.$$

Then

$$2=C4^0+\frac49,\\C=\frac{14}9.$$

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, don't get me wrong, but sometimes when I see posts like this, I imagine mathematicians as being these all-mighty creatures that doesn't know what to do with their powers.

Comment: @Lovsovs: fortunately, I am not a mathematician.

Answer (score 2):

The other question that you posted was multiple choice.  If this one is too, then there are probably some answers that can be eliminated.

Without meaning to discount others' comments about "there is no one right answer," given the scope of middle school math there are some reasonable things that can be said about the sequence $2,7,26,101,400,...$

- The next number should reasonably be bigger than $400$.  We don't see any example given that suggests the contrary.  (If $300$ were a choice, it could be eliminated.)
- The next number should be quite a bit bigger, given that the difference between consecutive elements in the sequence have a wider gap each time.  (If $401$ were a choice, it could be reasonably eliminated.)
- The next number should be close to four times bigger, looking at what's presented.  $101$ to $400$ is the strongest suggestion of this but it's reasonable for the other pairs of consecutive numbers as well.

Now, if the last point is noticed, then we can home in.  Starting with $2$, multiplying by $4$ each time would give

$$2,8,32,128,512$$

Not quite right, so let's look at the first two numbers.  Let's multiply by $4$ and subtract $1$ each time:

$$2, 7, 27, 107, 427$$

The second to third jump is only off by one, so maybe ... (maybe!) ... we increase the number we subtract each time by one:

$$2, 7, 26, 101, 400$$

*There* it is.

If we apply the pattern again, then we get $4\times 400 - 5 = 1595.$

I just looked at the sequence and played with it.